# Best way to implement voting in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voting

What's the best plugin these days for implementing voting on a Rails site?

Two I'm aware of are:

1. [vote_fu](http://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu/)
2. [acts_as_voteable](http://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

Comment: Likeable uses Redis to store likes: https://github.com/schneems/likeable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no general 'best' solution. Check out how both work and see what best fits what you want and what fits your application's needs. In this case, acts_as_votable allows voting on models. vote_fu contains more as it ads the concept of 'acts_as_voter' to limit the models that may vote. It also adds 'has_karma' to give karma based on user voting.

As you see, both are different options and only you know what best fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Coming in a bit late here, but from what I can tell vote_fu was inspired by acts_as_voteable (and supports its syntax), but is more actively developed.

Answer (score 3):

vote_fu is very outdated and isn't compatible with modern rails distributions (I'm using 3.2.5).  [Thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) has replaced it form Rails 3.x development.  Go with that or either [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) as they are still being maintained.

Thumbs_up has some extra options like built-in karma tracking.