# rails: how do I get started adding a very simple ajax Like/Dislike poll on a page of my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I finally got a chance to try to implement some simple ajax for a client, but have no idea where to start.

In my rails 3.1 app, my client wants to show a Like / Dislike poll.

It should show two links "Like" and "Dislike".

If a user clicks "Like", it would

1. increment number_of_likes:integer in the database.
2. display "You like this" under the links
3. use a cookie to track their answer (so next tme they view the page it still says "You like this"

and, ideally, does this via ajax.

Comment: So, what have you done already?

Comment: "no idea where to start" so turned to SO for some getting started suggestions. Googled and watched some railscasts but they are all doing (seemingly) much more complex tasks so hoping to find a gentle "hello world" for ajax. Thx for the tips below.

Comment: Yet at the same time you provided a list of three items. Go and try to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link out in SF

[Best way to implement voting in a Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397845/best-way-to-implement-voting-in-a-rails-application)

And if you  think it, like, dis-like is also kind of voting, you with a little effort you should be able to get something up and running